# Access to C# class from embedded IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I can access to python function from C# code.
Can i access to C# method of class from python script?
I have found only call from assembly, but not from embedded IronPython.

C#

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();

            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

            scope.SetVariable("test", t);

            engine.ExecuteFile("test.py", scope);

            Console.WriteLine("-------------------->");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string foo;
        public Test()
        {
            foo = "foo ok";
        }

        public void Do()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do()");
        }
    }
}
```

Python script

```
print(type(test).__name__)    # Test
print(test.foo)               # 'foo ok'
test.Do()                     # 'Test' object has no attribute 'Do'
```

How can i access to class method?

Comment: could you provide more info on your environment? This works for me on .net 4.6.1 and IPy 2.7.8.1 ... Output: `Test
foo ok
Do()
-------------------->`